# Woocommerce two shipping options at same time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fedex

i have a problem:

i have two shipping categories

1- **alfa**

2- **beta**

**alfa** should be 50$ by order (not by products) and if alfa products sum (without shipping and taxes) is more than 400$, alfa shipping is free.
i've done that rule, it works correctly only if alfa products and no others are inserted into chart.

**beta** should use fedEx shipping plugin to calculate, it works correctly only if beta products and no others are inserted into chart.

if i put alfa and beta products into chart i only get the alfa rules.

i set the rules with **Tree Table shipping** plugin in this way:

```
USA 
Child rules rate add sum of child rates

   ALFA
   Package all items at once
   Contains specified and maybe others ALFA any amount
   Calculate fees for all matching items at once
   Other shipping plugins FEDEX add all rates

   BETA
   Contains specified and maybe others BETA subtotal without tax and discount below 400$
   Charge Flat Fee 50$

   BETA
   Contains specified and maybe others BETA subtotal without tax and discount above 400$
   Free shipping
```

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: First split the cart by shipping class

Comment: @Mickey yes, i've already done. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Split the cart by shipping class and also select the "Capture" option so subsequent rules are not processed once a shipping class package has been processed. Create child rules and each one should contain their respective shipping class will the "all specified & no others" option so that each rule only applies to their respective shipping class.

Answer (score 0):

Got this [snippet from here](https://www.xadapter.com/split-cart-items-based-shipping-classallow-multiple-shipping-packages-one-order-based-shipping-class/)

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'wf_split_cart_by_shipping_class_group' );

    function wf_split_cart_by_shipping_class_group($packages){

        //Reset packages
        $packages               = array();

        //Init splitted package
        $splitted_packages      =   array();

        // Group of shipping class ids
        $class_groups   =   array(
            'group1'    =>  array(9,10),
            'group2'    =>  array(20),
            'group3'    =>  array(11,15,17),        
        );  

        // group items by shipping classes
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
            if ( $item['data']->needs_shipping() ) {

                $belongs_to_class_group =   'none';

                $item_ship_class_id =   $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();

                if($item_ship_class_id){

                    foreach($class_groups as $class_group_key   =>  $class_group){
                        if(in_array($item_ship_class_id, $class_group)){                
                            $belongs_to_class_group =   $class_group_key;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                }           

                $splitted_packages[$belongs_to_class_group][$item_key]  =   $item;
            }
        }

        // Add grouped items as packages 
        if(is_array($splitted_packages)){

            foreach($splitted_packages as $splitted_package_items){
                $packages[] = array(
                    'contents'        => $splitted_package_items,
                    'contents_cost'   => array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $splitted_package_items, 'line_total' ) ),
                    'applied_coupons' => WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons(),
                    'user'            => array(
                         'ID' => get_current_user_id(),
                    ),
                    'destination'    => array(
                        'country'    => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(),
                        'state'      => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(),
                        'postcode'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
                        'city'       => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(),
                        'address'    => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(),
                        'address_2'  => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2()
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        return $packages;
    }
```